# Regex for word not surrounded by alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex matching a specific word that is not surrounded by any alphanumeric character. My thought was to include a negation before and after:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d]myspecificword[^a-zA-Z\d]
```

So it would match:

```
myspecificword
_myspecificword_
-myspecificword
```

And not match:

```
notmyspecificword
myspecificword123
```

But this simple regex won't match the word by itself unless it is preceeded by a whitespace:

```
myspecificword   // no match
 myspecificword  // match
```

Using the flags "gmi" and testing with JavaScript. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't it be as simple as that?

https://regex101.com/r/BCkbVQ/3

Comment: Regex word boundary is `\b`

Comment: @Amy That won't work because underscore is considered a word character.

Comment: Use negative lookarounds. https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: It doesn't work because `[^a-zA-Z\d]` needs to match an actual character. There's no character at the beginning or end.

Comment: `/(?<![a-z\d])myspecificword(?![a-z\d])/ig` should work but keep in mind lookbehind is not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
(?<![^\s_-])myspecificword(?![^\s_-])
```

This says to match `myspecificword` when it surrounded, on both sides, by either the start/end of the input, whitespace, underscore, or dash.

### Demo

Comment: Positive and negative lookup is unnecessarily expensive, better use beginning and end of line

Comment: @Akxe Not true at all, and my answer is more efficient than your answer.

Comment: Oh, my apologies then, what was the catch then? Compatibility? I do remember avoiding using it...

Comment: Idgaf about compatibility, this is supposed to run on a single server. I value performance though.

Comment: I love double negatives. But since the OP said, "not surrounded by alphanumeric characters", then presumably `(myspecifword)` is acceptable. So why not: `(?<![^_\W])myspecificword(?![^_\W]` ?

Comment: I appreciate the answers but could someone enlighten me on why my regex won't work?

Comment: @GRoutar Read the comment posted on your question by Barmar 18 minutes ago.

Comment: @GRoutar The problem with your pattern is that it does not allow matches which have the start and/or end of the input as the boundary.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help, this works as intended.

Comment: Won't this regex eventually result in exponential-time though?

Answer (score 2):

It is not whitespace that is required but any symbol that is matches  `[^a-zA-Z\d]`.

You should use: ([Demo](https://regexr.com/4vbh3))

```
(?:^|[^a-zA-Z\d])myspecificword(?:[^a-zA-Z\d]|$)
```

The main benefit is support across all Regexp parsers.

Comment: Lookarounds would be more efficient than an alternation AFAIK.

Comment: @Akxe, An explanation of why this works would improves your answer.

Comment: @JithinPavithran best explanation will give you the https://regexr.com/, linked in the answer in the "explain" tab. It is an interactive explanation of what the regexp is.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly mean "not surrounded by alphanumerics other than `_` (and in your attempted regex you seem to be willing to match anything that isn't a letter or digit), then any of the following should be acceptable:

```
'myspecificword'
'_myspecificword_'
' myspecificword '
'-myspecificword-'
'(myspecificword)'
```

And the regex should be:

```
(?<![^_\W])myspecificword(?![^_\W])
```

```js
let tests = ['myspecificword',
             '_myspecificword_',
             ' myspecificword ', 
             '-myspecificword-', 
             '(myspecificword)', 
             'amyspecificword',
             '1myspecificword'
             ];
let regex = /(?<![^_\W])myspecificword(?![^_\W])/;
for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(regex.test(test));
}
```

The "accepted" answer will not match `(myspecificword)`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question is

> Regex for word not surrounded by alphanumeric characters

The other answers have all addressed a different question (which may well be the one intended):

> Regex for word neither preceded nor followed by alphanumeric characters

I will refer to these statements as #1 and #2 respectively.

If the specified word were `'cat'` and the string were `'9cat'`, `'cat'` is not *surrounded* by alphanumeric characters in the string, so there is a match with #1, but not with #2.

For #1, one could use the regex:

```
/cat(?!\p{Alpha}|(?<!\p{Alnum})cat/
```

("match 'cat' not followed by a Unicode alphanumeric character or 'cat' not preceded by a Unicode alphanumeric character"), though it's easier to test for the negation:

```
/(?<=\p{Alpha}cat(?<=\p{Alnum})/
```

The test passes if the string does not match this regex.

With interpretation #2, the regex is:

```
/(?<!\p{Alpha}cat(?!\p{Alnum})/
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

`/[^a-z0-9]?myspesificword[^a-z0-9]?/i`

Comment: your regex are using `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` which tells that must surrounded by non alphanumeric, add `?` so its optional

Comment: But this will also match those WITH alphanumeric characters surrounding it, such as `amyspesificwordz`.

Comment: Try this `/([^a-z0-9]?myspesificword[^a-z0-9]?)/i`

Comment: @Illya: I think you might want to read the question again.  This is looking for something that *will* match such strings as "myspecificword", "\_myspecificword\_", or "-myspecificword" and *will not* match ones such as "notmyspecificword" or "myspecificword123".

Comment: `/^([^a-z0-9]*myspesificword[^a-z0-9]*)$/i` like this?

Comment: Argh, my bad, I think it will match myspesificword on long text